# Can't read data from StreamReader

Tags: c#, streaming

I am trying build client app:

```
ShellStream mainStream = client.CreateShellStream("xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024); //the library's class which represents the main stream of data between client and server
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mainStream);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(mainStream); //wrappers for the main stream
```

There are sending request to server:

```
await writer.WriteAsync(command);
await writer.FlushAsync();
```

...and reading a response:

```
async Task<string> GetResponse(CancellationToken cts)
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] buffer = new char[128];
int i = 0;
while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)//when timeout is tick then cancel operation
     {
     while ((i = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
            sb.Append(buffer, 0, i);
            }
return sb.ToString();
```

The issue is I can't read a response from server, however the StreamReader has an internal char array, charBuffer, it HAS the response. Furthermore, GetResponse returns command which was written by StreamWriter. What is wrong here?

Edit: when I replaced `writer.WriteAsync(command);` by `writer.WriteLineAsync(command);` it began to work. However when I send the specific command (`geth --verbosity 0`) it does not again. This behavior is very strange for me.

Comment: Checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And what is `ReadStream` and `WriteStream` ?

Comment: @Jim, I fixed it. Actually it is StreamReader and StreamWriter respectively